# Modular arithmetic and Euclidean Rings

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The question posted below is from a previous exam question that I attempted as part of my revision for my upcoming number theory exam. Parts (a) and (b) were fine but I have no idea how to attempt (c) so I left it blank. I contacted my lecturer who just told me to look at the definition of a Euclidean ring, but I still don’t know how to attempt either parts of (c). Could someone please give me some hints on how to attempt them?

[image]

Comment: Did you look up the definition of an Euclidean ring ? Compare it with the usual division of positive integers with residue.

Comment: Oh ok, I see how to do ci) now because of the residue. Thanks for that. Could you give me a hint on how to generalise this result please?

Comment: I do not remember the full proof. It is based on the element $x$ with smallest possible $d(x)$ of an ideal $a-bR$, for which $d(x)=0$ holds if and only if $b|a$

Comment: @Peter Principal ideal domain. So nothing about principles:)